# Are there any instances where Instagram allows third party uploads?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone know if there are any instances where Instagram allows a third party to upload photos?  I'm referring to businesses uploading photos to their account without using Instagram's phone app, not a consumer use.

If this B2B possibility exists, how does one approach Instagram about getting access to the API?

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible. The amount of spam that would be generated by having access to API features allowing someone to upload photos without the task of having to do so from the application would be astronomical. What is the objective you are looking to achieve? Maybe it can be accomplished in another manner.

Comment: I feel like this question is best asked to Instagram.

Comment: @Daniel - thanks for your reply. The idea is to post a stream of photos rather than individual shots. Not necessarily spam, but as I research, I'm starting to see this is outside the typical use of Instagram's service!

Comment: @NightShadeQueen - Great idea, but there is any contact info on their site!